# Trying to get a number from modal bootstrap and do autoincrement when button trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

Guys!

I've a problem when I try to increment an element which it has value=1. My suppose is; When the button plus goes to trigger I'll do autoincrement. can you guys point my fault ?

Thanks in advance.

```
   $("#plus").on('click',function(){

var teste = 1;
$("#valor").val(teste);


});
```

here is my Modal;  [Modal Bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjg27.png)

PS: I'm using that structure at my project,  but with other names and id's.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle so people here can help you better?

Comment: right now it seems you keep setting `#valor` value to 1

Comment: do you want `#valor` to increment on each click on `#plus`?

Comment: Yes, I do Yoni.

Answer (score 2):

On each click you reset the var to "1".

This should work:

```
   var teste = 1;
   $("#plus").on('click',function(){
       teste = teste + 1; // or teste++; // or teste += 1;
       $("#valor").val(teste);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will always set the value to 1 and not increment it.

You can increment the current value of your target, adding 1 to the current value of your target.

> Make sure you `parseInt` the value or you get incorrect results when using `val()`

```
$("#plus").on('click', function() {
    var $valor = $("#valor");
    var currentValue = parseInt($valor.val())

    $("#valor").val((currentValue || 0) + 1);
});
```

```js
$("#plus").on('click', function() {
  var $valor = $("#valor");
  var currentValue = parseInt($valor.val())

  $("#valor").val((currentValue || 0) + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="valor" type="text" readonly=true>
<button id="plus">Add 1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you..

Remove inner if if you do need value less than zero.

```js
$(".changval").on('click',function(){
  var sign=$(this).data('sign');
  
  if(sign==1)
    $('#valor').val((parseInt($('#valor').val())||0)+1);
  else if(sign==2)
  {
    $('#valor').val((parseInt($('#valor').val())||0)-1);
    if($('#valor').val()<0)
      $('#valor').val(0);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="valor">

<!--
<button class="changval" onclick="$('#valor').val((parseInt($('#valor').val())||0)+1);">Plus</button>
<button class="changval" onclick="$('#valor').val((parseInt($('#valor').val())||0)-1);">Minus</button>

<button class="changval" onclick="$('#valor').val((parseInt($('#valor').val())||0)-1);">Minus 2</button>
-->

<button class="changval" data-sign="1">Plus</button>
<button class="changval" data-sign="2">Minus</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#plus").on('click',function(){
   let incrementedValue = ($("#valor").val() || 0) + 1;
   $("#valor").val(incrementedValue);
});
```

Comment: Your code will not increment the value by `1` but append `1` to it instead, resulting in `1` then `11`, `111`, etc..